# Finder is not saving my changes at Desktop (i.e Arrangements)

Tags: finder, desktop, high-sierra

Less than a week ago, I just upgraded my MacBook Pro (Early 2015) to macOS 10.13.1. 
I am not sure if the problem was caused by this. Everything was fine, nothing went wrong during the installation, but after a few days I noticed that Finder wasn't saving my Desktop looks/arrangements.

**Yes,** I tried to delete Finder preferences and restart Finder.

**Yes,** I tried to delete .DS_Store file.

**Yes,** I tried to delete and recreate ~/Desktop folder.

I also looked at [this apple discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2736762?start=0), [this post on OSXDaily](http://osxdaily.com/2011/09/21/stop-desktop-icons-changing-positions-after-restart-mac/) and [this post at macosx.com](https://macosx.com/threads/lion-cannot-move-desktop-icons.320888/) but none of the solutions worked.

So now, here is my question: How can I make Finder save my desktop arrangements without reinstall?

**EDIT:** I just did a Disk First Aid now, and it didn’t seem to help.

Comment: Have you used Disk Utility to do First Aid on your boot disk?

Comment: I did it now but it didn’t help.